# How to set build version automatically in .net core projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, version

In previos version of .net on AssemblyInfo.cs if we change

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

to

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

and compile our project build version compiler sets automatically build version to dll or.. files.

in .net core we have this

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
},
```

how can we do it on .net core on UI tier?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into the Project properties under Application Tab and set the assembly information usig the available "Assembly Information" button. This allows the Title/description/Copyright notice/Assembly version and neutral language to be set. But ultimately it just sets the values into the Project.json file

```
"title": "project name",
"copyright": "company copyright",
"description": "project description",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
```