# How do I autoincrement the Package Version revision number when using a .Net Core format project file in VS2019

Tags: c#, tfs, csproj, visual-studio-2019

Previous answers to this question refer to editing the AssembyInfo.cs file to set the Assembly Version. I am generating a NuGet package using the new leaner .Net Core format of .csproj file for .Net Framework 4.6.1, and there is no AssemblyInfo.cs (or it's auto-generated and deleted).

If I try to set the Package Version property to 1.0.2.* in the project properties in VS2019, I get a popup error:

[image: A wildcard ("*") is not allowed in this field]

If possible, how can I get the revision number to auto-increment, ideally so on each build the number is incremented (1.0.2.45 => 1.0.2.46) and the number is retained across releases (1.0.2.46 => 1.0.3.47, manually editing the build/release number).

Note: I've already looked at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650/automatically-update-version-number), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202306/how-can-i-autoincrement-the-assembly-build-number-in-visual-studio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946808/how-to-set-build-version-automatically-in-net-core-projects) and they all refer to the AssemblyVersion attribute. I want to update the Package Version (which is simply the Version in the CSProj file).

---

Update: One of the answers suggested a couple of GIT versions tools. I forgot to mention that TFS is used for a lot of the projects I want to use this on; these are work projects shared with other team members and are well established so could not easily be migrated to GIT without a lot of discussion even if it didn't get a simple veto by management as an unnecessary change.

Comment: There is a VS 2019 tag ;)

Comment: Did you see this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core I think its the same question, but pleas confirm

Answer (score 4):

First, on wildcards in assembly and package versions:

The wildcard for assembly (not package) versions is discouraged from being used - the new default for "sdk-style" projects use a compiler feature called "deterministic build" which aims to produce a binary identical output for every time the same unchanged source code is compiled. This mode does not allow for wildcards in assembly versions, which would change every 2 seconds.

However, this feature can be turned off by setting

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you then use a wildcard in your assembly version, the compiler will update your version based on the current time.

To re-use this assembly version for the package version, you need to add some additional build logic to your project file as described here: [MSBuild /t:pack Nuget-Package has always the same Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818235/msbuild-tpack-nuget-package-has-always-the-same-version/47819996#47819996)

What I encourage to do:

A lot of projects use their git history for versioning, incrementing the version based on the git commit count.

I suggest looking into tools like [Nerdbank.GitVersioning](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning) (lightweight and easy to use)  or [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (more features and better documentation) that allow you to configure how your versions can be automatically derived from the branches/tags that are being built.

Comment: I reasd about "deterministic build" and understood the reason for it. But am surprised no-one has encountered the need to automatically increment the version when a change *is* made. At the moment, to test a change in a package, I have to make the change and then update the assembly and package version numbers to ensure that it gets seen as a new version even if it's in a local repository. I wouldn't have thought I was the first person to want a VS extension to automate this. The Git version tools probably aren't that useful to me, since I'm using TFS.

Comment: Similar things can be done vor TFVC changest numbers but manually.. But there aren't a lot of tools since TFS supports Git and there are build tasks for it that parse GitVersion for example. You could also use your build definition to increment a version that is stored somewhere.

Comment: Thanks,We are moving to Git for new projects, but I was hoping someone had already put something together for TFS to save my having to do it!

Comment: @StarNamer Seen this? https://github.com/devlooped/GitInfo

Answer (score 2):

There's no auto increment support for versioning nuget packages. You need to figure out/set the version number manually (or programmatically) through something like msbuild, a continuous integration platform, or third party tool.